# How to choose and work with a drop down list in js

Tags: javascript

I got this problem. I created a drop down list for choosing the algorithm to work with. It works with the first option but not all of them. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

```
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
var form3 = document.getElementById('form3');

var formArray = [];                     
formArray.push(form1.innerHTML);
formArray.push(form2.innerHTML);
formArray.push(form3.innerHTML);

//select drop down list//

function changeToCal() {
   dropDownList.selectedIndex--;
   document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = formArray[dropDownList.selectedIndex];
}

//Calculate // 

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", 
    function(event) {
        var fieldy = document.getElementById('fieldy');
        var fieldx = document.getElementById('fieldx');
        var resultField = document.getElementById('resultField');

        var x = parseFloat(fieldx.value); 
        var y = parseFloat(fieldy.value); 

        if(!fieldy.value || !fieldx.value) {
        alert("Please enter numbers in the fields!");
        } else if (dropDownList.selectedIndex = 1) {
            var result = (y / 100) * x;
            resultField.innerText = "Answer: " + result + "."
            event.preventDefault();

        } else if (dropDownList.selectedIndex = 2) {
            var result = (100 / y) * x;
            resultField.innerText = "Answer: " + result + "."
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (dropDownList.selectedIndex = 3) {
            var result = (y / x) * 100; 
            resultField.innerText = "Answer: " + result + " %."
            event.preventDefault();        
        } else {
            resultField.innerText = "Error"
            event.preventDefault(); 
      }

        }
            );
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMZNwQ

Comment: Your code? Would be a huge help

Comment: Please show the necessary code along with your question itself then it will be useful for the readers and it will improve the quality of your question?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
} else if (dropDownList.selectedIndex = 1) {
```

needs to use a comparison equals operator rather than an assignment equals operator:

```
} else if (dropDownList.selectedIndex === 1) {
```

The other if/else clauses are similarly incorrect.

I highly recommend using a decent IDE, it would highlight potential mistakes like this for you.

You will also need to change this:

```
dropDownList.selectedIndex--;
document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = formArray[dropDownList.selectedIndex];
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = formArray[dropDownList.selectedIndex - 1];
```

The `selectedIndex` is live, if you change it using `--` that will cause the selected value to be updated.

The way the result is output assumes there is an `<h3>` with the id `resultField` but only one of your forms has that id set.

Other miscellaneous suggestions include...

The `id` attributes need to be unique throughout the document. You currently have 3 hidden forms and you copy around the HTML, leading to 4 elements with each id (`resultField`, `fieldx`, `fieldy`). Whether `document.getElementById` grabs the right one is down to luck.

Rather than copying around the `innerHTML` of those forms you'd be better off simply showing and hiding the existing forms using CSS. Alternatively you could use just 1 form and update the relevant text to match the current algorithm.

Listening for the `submit` event of the form seems odd. Why not use a regular button and listen for the `click` event?

If you do decide to keep the 3 forms I would suggest registering separate button handlers for each one. The fact that so much of your code is inside a big if/else is a sign that you actually need multiple functions rather than a single function that has to figure out which mode it is in. The code they share could be factored out if appropriate.